# How to do join with objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

So I am converting a old project with ordinary SQL queries to a ORM using the Entity Framework. So I have created database model like this:

[image: Database model]

So I had this old query which I want to translate to a linq expression

```
SELECT UGLINK.USERNAME 
FROM GMLINK 
INNER JOIN UGLINK 
ON GMLINK.GROUPID = UGLINK.GROUPID 
WHERE (((GMLINK.MODULEID)=%ID%))
```

And the problem I have is that I can't figure out how to do a join query using the objects.
Instead I have to go though the properties like this (which seems to be working):

```
// So this is one of the module objects that is located in a listView in the GUI
Module m = ModuleList.selectedItem as Module;

/* Now I want to fetch all the User objects that, 
 * via a group, is connected to a certain module */
var query = context.gmLink
    .Join(context.ugLink,
          gmlink => gmlink.GroupId,
          uglink => uglink.GroupId,
          (gmlink, uglink) => new { gmLink = gmlink, ugLink = uglink })
    .Where(gmlink => gmlink.gmLink.ModuleId == m.ModuleId)
    .Select(x => x.ugLink.User);
```

So as I said this works, but as you see I kind of have to connect the modules via the link tables properties `.GroupId` and `.ModuleId` and so on. Instead I would like to go through the objects created by EF.

I wanted to write a question a bit like this, but can't figure out how to do it, is it at all possible?

```
var query = context.User
            .Select(u => u.ugLink
                .Select(uglink => uglink.Group.gmLink
                    .Where(gmLink => gmLink.Module == m)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working:

```
var query = context.gmLink
    .Where(gmlink => gmlink.ModuleId == m.ModuleId)
    .SelectMany(gmlink => gmlink.Group.ugLink)
    .Select(uglink => uglink.User);
```

It's impossible to filter gmLinks using `.Where(gmlink => gmlink.Module == m)` in EF, so this comparison needs to be done using identifiers. Another option is `.Where(gmlink => gmlink.Module.ModuleId == m.ModuleId)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have lazy loading enabled, you do not need to apply specific join notation (you can access the navigation properties directly) - but the queries that are ran against SQL are inefficient (generally the results are returned in a number of different select statements).

My preference is to disable lazy loading on the context, and use .Include() notation to join tables together manually, resulting in generally more efficient queries. .Include() is used to explicitly join entities in Entity Framework.

Join() is misleading, and not appropriate for joining tables in EF.

So, to replicate this statement:

```
SELECT UGLINK.USERNAME 
FROM GMLINK 
INNER JOIN UGLINK 
ON GMLINK.GROUPID = UGLINK.GROUPID 
WHERE (((GMLINK.MODULEID)=%ID%))
```

You would use the following:

```
var query = context.gmLink
    .Include(x => x.Group.gmLink)
    .Where(x => x.ModuleId == myIdVariable)
    .Select(x => new {
        UserName = x.Group.ugLink.UserName
    });
```

Assuming that your navigation properties are correctly set up. I have not tested this, so I'm not 100% on the syntax.

You should really run SQL profiler while you write and run LINQ to Entity queries against your database, so you can understand what's actually being generated and run against your database. A lot of the time, an EF query may be functioning correctly, but you may experience performance issues when deployed to a production system.

[This whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) might help you out.

Comment: Hmm, Ahh ok, that seemed very very neat, but my initial expression did only get the usernames and not the whole user. I didn't notice that. Sorry for the inconvenience but I need the User object...

Comment: Updated to output just the user object. You can project using .Select() into whatever form the predicate input allows.

Comment: Correct you are, sorry - hard to write bespoke code accurately when you don't have VS in front of you :)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either, since `Gourp.ugLink` is a List of ´ugLink's´ rather than just a ´ugLink´...

Comment: Include() is still definitely the way to go. Maybe my code is misleading as I don't fully understand your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but something like this:

```
var users = context.User
    .Where(x => x.ugLink
        .Any(y => context.gmLink
                    .Where(z => z.ModuleId == m)
                    .Select(z => z.GroupId)
                    .Contains(y.GroupId)
        )
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, this works with the exception that m has to be substituted with m.ModuleId, so in a sense this is better that my attempt, however it still joins on `.ModuleId` and `.GroupId` ie. the primitives and not the objects (but maybe that is the only way to go?